# NetworkStream missing data

Tags: c#, networkstream

The data in question is a PNG file prefixed by it's size as an int.

```
-Sending:
ns.Write(BitConverter.GetBytes((int)data.Length),0,4);
ns.Write(data, 0, data.Length);

-Reading:
byte[] sizearray = new byte[4];
ns.Read(sizearray, 0, 4);
int dataSize = BitConverter.ToInt32(sizearray,0);

byte[] data = new byte[dataSize];
ns.Read(data, 0, dataSize);
```

The recieved data is then saved to a file. I've also tried this with BeginRead/EndRead with the same result.

The issue is, while this works for most smaller images, it doesn't receive an image which is more then a few KB. The dataSize reads correctly, but after a few thousand bytes each time (~2900), the rest of the received data is 0. [Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8NBWg.png)

Have I overlooked something, like a limit on how much can be sent at once?

Comment: Are you flushing/closing the stream?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're ignoring the return value of `Read`. Don't do that. `Read` doesn't wait until it's read *all* of the data you requested. You should read in a loop until you've read everything you need to:

```
byte[] data = new byte[dataSize];
int index = 0;
while (index < dataSize)
{
    int bytesRead = ns.Read(data, index, dataSize - index);
    if (bytesRead <= 0)
    {
        // Or whatever exception you want
        throw new InvalidDataException("Premature end of stream");
    }
    index += bytesRead;
}
```

In theory, you need to do the same even when reading `dataSize`, although in practice I *doubt* whether you'll receive fewer than 4 bytes in one read.

You might want to use a `BinaryReader` wrapped around the stream - then you could use `ReadInt32` and `ReadBytes`, where `ReadBytes` will do the looping for you. (You'd still need to check the return value, but it would be simpler than doing it yourself.)

Comment: Thanks, I hadn't realized that Read only read in chunks, and BinaryReader works well.

Answer (score 1):

```
ns.Read(data, 0, dataSize);
```

Here's at least one of your problems: [`Read()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.networkstream.read.aspx) returns how many bytes were read, it's not guaranteed that `dataSize` bytes were read.

> This method reads data into the buffer parameter and returns the
>   number of bytes successfully read. If no data is available for
>   reading, the Read method returns 0. The Read operation reads as much
>   data as is available, up to the number of bytes specified by the size
>   parameter.